# web.xml : URL mapping

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, web.xml

I have these two lines in my `web.xml`
`<url-pattern>/</url-pattern> : Index Servlet`
and
`<url-pattern>/login</url-pattern> : Login Servlet`
but whem I open `http://localhost:8084/login/`, it goes to `Index Servlet` and when I open `http://localhost:8084/login`, it goes to `Login Servlet`.
Is there any difference in `http://localhost:8084/login/` and `http://localhost:8084/login`?
My `web.xml`

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Index</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Index</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Login</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

and

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Index</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Can you provide the piece of `web.xml` having the URL mapping configurations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The URL pattern of `/` has a special meaning. It namely indicates the "Default Servlet" URL pattern. So **every request** which does *not* match any of the other more specific URL patterns in `web.xml` will ultimately end up in this servlet. Note that this thus also covers static files like plain vanilla HTML/CSS/JS and image files! Normally, the "Default Servlet" is already provided by the servlet container itself (see e.g. [Tomcat's `DefaultServlet` documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/default-servlet.html)). Overriding the "Default Servlet" in your own webapp should be done with extreme care and definitely not this way.

You need to give your index servlet a different URL pattern. It should be the same as the one you definied in `<welcome-file>`.

So in case of

```xml
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

you need to map the index servlet as follows

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Index</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Using an URL rewrite filter as suggested by other answer is unnecessary for the particular purpose you had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a difference. Either use something like [UrlRewriteFilter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) to remove the trailing slash, or have your web.xml specify both:

```
<url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
```

and

```
<url-pattern>/login/*</url-pattern>
```

As mapping to the login servlet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it go to Login Servlet.
why not try Spring URL Mapping

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String demo(ModelMap map) {

String something = name;

// Do manipulation

return "login"; // Forward to login.jsp
}
```

Watch this [Spring MVC Framework Tutorial](http://youtu.be/Q6hZQ5SzGyM)