# Can I change URL name in Java?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, filter

I want to change My URL name in Java.

Example

Suppose my URL name is www.xyz.com/join.html

I want to change this URL in my address bar to
www.xyz.com/register-user

Can anybody suggest any way to achieve this?

Thank You.

Comment: You could handle this mapping in your `web.xml` file, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071131/web-xml-url-mapping).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen But I want dynamically change my URL suppose my currently Url is http://www.example.com/product.jsp?productId=123 and I want to show as http://www.example.com/product-name  If U know about SEO I want to apply SEO in this Link so any body can visit this and google will find immediately the page.

Comment: What all are you using? Just the servlets or any other framework?

Comment: @AbdullahKhan JSP and Servlet Only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fix your mappings in [`web.xml`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311065/what-is-web-xml-file-and-what-are-all-things-can-i-do-with-it)

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RegisterUserServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.blahBlah.RegisterUserServlet</servlet-class> //Your servlets path
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RegisterUserServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/register-user</url-pattern> //if the url exactly matches register-user RegisterUserServlet will be called.
</servlet-mapping>
```

Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311065/what-is-web-xml-file-and-what-are-all-things-can-i-do-with-it) on SO and this [`blog`](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/web-xml.html) for more on what `web.xml` is.

Comment: You give an answer for servlet but what should be done for JSP?

Comment: You can do it the same way. Instead of giving the class path in the `servlet-class` tag you now have to give path for your `jsp`'s.

Comment: Also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091762/url-mapping-for-jsp) answer.

Comment: Thank You... I think it helps me.